# Can't get my functions in my contract to run (Solidity)

Tags: solidity

With the following, I attempt to test it, but nothing happens when I do my set (and therefore my get). No error, no output... nothing. :(

Am I missing something obvious?

---

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract MyPLMPOC {

    string private myContractName;
    uint private myContractLength;

    function setContractName(string memory myNewContractName) public {
         myContractName = myNewContractName;
    }

    function getContractName() public  returns(string memory)  {
        return myContractName;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function getContractName() public view returns(string memory)  {
        return myContractName;
    }
```

function with "view"  does not create transaction, only read values instantly from state

function without view creates transaction, needing time to be collected in a block.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I hate when it should be an obvious answer. Drat!